# React testing library getByLabelText -Label with special characters

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

```
it('render the field with label having the special characters', () => {
  expect(screen.getByTestId('foo')).toHaveTextContent('About(En)'); // works
  expect(screen.getByLabelText(/About(En)/u)).toBeInTheDocument(); // not working
});
```

The first expect is true, but the second giving error

```
 Error: Unable to find a label with the text of: /About(En)/u
```

I want to use `getByLabelText` instead of `getByTestId`, becuase `getByTestId` needs addtional attribute on each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to use quotes instead of the regex, or you have to escape the parenthesis in your regex.

I created a very simple react-app that shows this working.
Check App.js/App.test.js

You can download and run the code:
https://github.com/lviviani/so-69195225-poc

For example:

```
it('render the field with label having the special characters', () => {
  render(<App />);
  expect(screen.getByTestId('foo')).toHaveTextContent('About(En)'); // works
  expect(screen.getByLabelText('About(En)')).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByLabelText(/about\(en\)/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you can post the snippet of code under test.